# Better way to check for variable empty or null or parent is null

Tags: java

I have a condition in java as follows:

```
if(a == null || a.getRecords() == null || a.getRecords().isEmpty()) {
}
```

Is there a better way to write this condition using some google guava library or apache library?

Comment: Define “better”.

Comment: What you are doing is indeed the better way to do it. If you are doing the second half of checking the collection to be null or empty at more places then you can extract the logic to a separate static method. Google Guava/Commons-lang just does the same thing. If you already have the library in the class path then use `CollectionUtils` from commons-lang, else you can handle it yourself.

Comment: why not start with if(a!=null)

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan it sure is **not** the only way - see first answer

Comment: "Better" is a matter of opinion. However, *another* option is Java's `Objects.requireNonNull()`, which will throw an exception if the argument is null. When choosing among options, consider readability.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, I only meant to say it is the only better way or efficient way to do it. I have corrected my comment.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan it sure is **not** the **only** available way - again, see Samuel's answer..

Comment: `if (firstNonNull(firstNonNull(a, someNonNullInstance).getRecords(), emptyList()).isEmpty())` is *a* way of doing it.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I know you can do the same simple thing in 100 different ways, I only meant to say there is no better and simple way to do it in Java apart from what OP has asked.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan I still think that (again) first answer can also be "better"... since "better" is very broad, subjective,...

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger For long I have thought better is lot of objectivity with little subjectivity in it. In software, I related better with simplicity, performance and no unnecessary complexity. However, this is a very subjective opinion in itself

Comment: A better approach would be to avoid the need to write such a condition in the first place.  It's undesirable that `a.getRecords() == null` is used to mean the same thing as `a.getRecords().isEmpty()` (an empty list is typically a very natural implementation of the null object pattern), and it seems undersirable that you permit `a` itself to be `null` at all.

Comment: Does this condition precede a redundant call to *getRecords()* that is presumed to return the same value on the second call? Because that can be a bad presumption, leading to fragile code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solution is better, but you can use an `Optional` for that:

```
boolean result = !Optional.ofNullable(a)
        .map(MyClass::getRecords)
        .filter(List::isEmpty)
        .isPresent();

if (result) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*A* way of doing it is like so, using the [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern):

```
if (firstNonNull(firstNonNull(a, someNonNullInstance).getRecords(), emptyList()).isEmpty()) {
```

Where [`MoreObjects.firstNonNull`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/MoreObjects.html#firstNonNull-T-T-) and [`Collections.emptyList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyList--) are used.

This assumes that `someNonNullInstance` is an instance of the same type as `a`, with an empty records list (or whatever the type of `getRecords()` is).

I wouldn't recommend this, however. The original code is far more readable (I would go so far as to say that this is quite *un*readable).

You could make it more readable by breaking up the expression:

```
TypeOfA anA = firstNonNull(a, someNonNullInstance);
List<Record> aList = firstNonNull(anA.getRecords(), emptyList());
if (aList.isEmpty()) {
  // ...
}
```

but it still feels far worse that the original.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are working with collection here , If you use the Apache Commons Collections library in your project, you may use the `CollectionUtils.isEmpty and MapUtils.isEmpty()` methods which respectively check if a collection or a map is empty or null (i.e. they are "null-safe").

Also You can use org.apache.commons.lang.Validate's "notEmpty" method:
`Validate.notEmpty(myCollection) ->` Validate that the specified argument collection is neither null nor a size of zero (no elements); otherwise throwing an exception.

When you use spring then you can use

```
boolean isNullOrEmpty = org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils.isEmpty(obj);
```

where obj is any [map,collection,array,anything...]

But it seems To check an object is null is easy but to verify if it's empty is tricky as object can have many private or inherited variables and nested objects which should all be empty. For that All need to be verified or some isEmpty() method be in all objects which would verify the objects emptiness.

You can't do it directly, you should provide your own way to check this. Eg.

```
class MyClass {
  Object attr1, attr2, attr3;

  public boolean isValid() {
    return attr1 != null && attr2 != null && attr3 != null;
  }
}
```

Or make all fields final and initialize them in constructors so that you can be sure that everything is initialized.